# How do I specify the password in the MYSQL connection URL?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently using this connection URL for MYSQL

```
mysql://root:macbookair@localhost:3306/test_db
```

and getting this error.

```
[INFO] require: ./mysql
[INFO] connecting
[ERROR] Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How do I specify the password in the MYSQL connection URL?

Comment: Which language you are using to write your program?

Answer (score 57):

Got it now.

The connection URL is in this format:

```
mysql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>
```

thus the password worked when I replaced `macbookair` in my url with the password.

Comment: what if the password contains @ ??

Comment: replace @ it with %40 in password string

Comment: What if your password contains `%40`?  Is there some encoding scheme standard for all forms of connecting to MySQL via connect string?  Are they always URL-encoded?

Comment: %2540 as the encoding for % is %25 @bsplosion

Comment: Interesting - it looks like only `: / ? # [ ] @` characters have to be escaped, at least based on [MongoDB's documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#components).  It seems like it's functionally the same treatment as required for escaping URL query param values.

Answer (score 16):

try below

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/organizer?user=root&password=root
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

Standard

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Specifying TCP port

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;
```