# No suitable driver found java mysql libgdx

Tags: java, mysql, sql, libgdx

I am trying to link my project to the db with mysql but I get this error:

No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test;databaseName=test;user=root;password=

I have the mysql connector, so i see the database and the table but i can't connect with code

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver   is **not** for mysql. where did you get the connection string?

Comment: I post my code below

Comment: remove "`jdbc:sqlserver://" +` as you pass it aölready in address

Comment: Like this? Look the code

Comment: your connection string must look like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33854150/5193536  so you must exchange the part of the strong with our variables

Comment: My string url like this? "mysql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>"

Comment: yes like the link showed you

Comment: I did: "mysql://<root>:<root>@<localhost>:<3306>/<test>"; but don't work

Comment: without the < and > they are only to signalize placeholder

Comment: I try: String url = "mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/test"; same problem. Maybe i need: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); ?

Comment: yes according to this here https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database

Comment: Don't work... i don't know

Comment: take the code form the last link and try it without any changes, and don't work isn't a proper error message, so here could be anything wrong